# Picture about what's going on in a proof for knot theory

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

In Lickorish's 'An Introduction to Knot Theory' after Proposition 6.3 one reads:

> Now suppose that $F$ is a Seifert surface for an oriented link $L$ in $\mathbb{S}^3$, so that $\partial F=L$. Let $N$ be a regular neighbourhood of $L$, a disjoint union of solid tori that 'fatten' the components of $L$. Let $X$ be the closure of $\mathbb{S}^3-N$. Then $F\cap X$ is $F$ with a (collar) neighbourhood of $\partial F$ removed. Thus $F\cap X$ is just a copy of $F$ and, just to simplify notation, it will be regarded as actually being $F$. This $F$ has a regular neighbourhood $F\times [-1,1]$ in $X$, with $F$ identified with $F\times 0$ and the notation chosen so that the meridian of every component of $L$ enters the neighbourhood at $F\times -1$ and leaves it at $F\times 1$.

I would mainly like to ask if someone is able to give me a little sketch/picture of what's going on here any why we have '*Then $F\cap X$ is $F$ with a (collar) neighbourhood of $\partial F$ removed.*'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $L$ to be the unit circle sitting in some plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $F$ to be the unit disk in that plane. Then $N$ is a solid torus (thickened $L$) which "cuts" into $F$ near the boundary $\partial F = L$. That's the visual to see how the collar neighborhood of $\partial F$ sits inside $N$. Because $N$ has a radial coordinate (measured as distance away from $L$), and so along $F$ this radial coordinate defines the collar neighborhood of $F$.

Comment: Actually taking the unknot as an example is a nice idea, I see what's going in here. Thank you very much. Do you also know what 'meridian of every component of $L$' means? I am not sure what meridian means here.

Comment: In my example, the neighborhood of F is the "thickening" orthogonal to the plane. The solid torus N has longitudinal circles (such as L!) and the meridian is the other loop (orthogonal to longitudes) on N which grips around L.

Comment: Again L in general will be disjoint collection of loops, but I'm focusing on a single loop.

Comment: @leparisien: a meridian of a link is a small circle that links the link once. It bounds a small disk that hits the link in one point. For a link with $m$ components, there will be $m$ essentially different meridians.

Comment: Thank you both it helped a lot!

Comment: One more question: $F\times [-1,1]$ is supposed to be a neighbourhood of $F$ in $X$, so it doesn't intersect with the torus (I am in you example, @Chris Gerig). So how is 'notation chosen such that the meridian of every component of $L$ enters the neighbourhood at $F\times -1$' meant?

Comment: It will intersect the solid torus (solid torus and thickened F are 3-dimensional). Take the picture of the solid torus having 3 coordinates, 1 coordinate flowing along L, 1 coordinate entering radially into F, and the other coordinate (orthogonal to those 2 coordinates) is the thickening parameter [-1,1]. As a final remark, possibly irrelevant to you: The solid torus is an honest *tubular* neighborhood of L, but the thickened F is not an honest *tubular* neighborhood of F... With our F = disk, the thickened F is a solid cylinder, but a tubular neighborhood would be a solid ball encasing F.

Comment: But  N = torus lies not in X , the neighbourhood of F  does. So I don't understand why the intersection is not empty.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that X isn't the ambient manifold. The boundary of N is the boundary of X, so view the "meridian" as the loop that lies on the boundary :-)

Comment: Alright, but in this case there isn't really a F x -1 where the meridian enters N. I imagine F x [-1,1] being a cylinder in the hole of the torus. So the meridian touches this cylinder but it enters nothing. Besides can you explain what is meant geometrically by cutting X along F?

Comment: I'm abusing notation: The "meridian" doesn't have to lie on N, but to make it clear what a meridian is, I was using the ones on N. So imagine taking a slightly bigger N (call it N') and then use the meridian on (the boundary of) N'. A meridian is any loop that "grips around" L once (with positive orientation), which I was visualizing for you by using N.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you very much! And if I cut $X$ along $F$, why the result is $\mathbb{D}^2\times [-1,1]$?